# Logic APP - API call - An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to load in some api data with the example payload below and get the following error msg: "ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded."

What I'm trying to do is load all the data even if the "option" array is empty. Using the below if statement works and does the trick but it fails the logic app.

What's the best approach to remove this error?

Using the following if statement:

```
if(
    empty(items('For_each')?['options']),json('[
{"options": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": {
            "English": "N/A"
          },
          "value": "N/A",
          "properties": null,
          "image": {
            "sLink": "N/A"
          }
}
]
}]'),
    items('For_each')?['options']

)
```

Example payload:

```
{
  "result_ok": true,
  "total_count": 12,
  "page": 1,
  "total_pages": 1,
  "results_per_page": 12,
  "data": [
    
    {
      "id": 5,
      "base_type": "Question",
      "type": "IMAGE",
      "title": {
        "English": "I like apples."
      },
      "shortname": "",
     
      
      "options": [
        {
          "id": 10017,
          "title": {
            "English": "L1"
          },
          "value": "L1",
          "properties": null,
          "image": {
            "sLink": "j1"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 10016,
          "title": {
            "English": "L2"
          },
          "value": "L2",
          "properties": null,
          "image": {
            "sLink": "j2"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 10015,
          "title": {
            "English": "L3"
          },
          "value": "L3",
          "properties": null,
          "image": {
            "sLink": "j3"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 10014,
          "title": {
            "English": "L4"
          },
          "value": "L4",
          "properties": null,
          "image": {
            "sLink": "j4"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": 10013,
          "title": {
            "English": "L5"
          },
          "value": "L5",
          "properties": {
            "show_rules": null,
            "show_rules_logic_map": null
          },
          "image": {
            "sLink": "j5"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "base_type": "Question",
      "type": "ESSAY",
      "title": {
        "English": "Why?"
      },
      "shortname": "",
     
    
      "options": [
        
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have mentioned can be caused because of many reasons. However, I tried to reproduce the issue as below.

[image]

So, while appending I have tried to convert the result into json and appended the same to the newly created array. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

```
if(empty(items('For_each_2')?['options']),json('{\r\n \"id\": 1,\r\n \"title\": {\r\n \"English\": \"N/A\"\r\n },\r\n \"value\": \"N/A\",\r\n \"properties\": null,\r\n \"image\": {\r\n \"sLink\": \"N/A\"\r\n }\r\n}'),items('For_each_2')?['options'])
```

Results:

[image]

Resultant Array:

```
[
  {
    "options": {
      "id": 1,
      "title": {
        "English": "N/A"
      },
      "value": "N/A",
      "properties": null,
      "image": {
        "sLink": "N/A"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "options": [
      {
        "id": 10017,
        "title": {
          "English": "L1"
        },
        "value": "L1",
        "properties": null,
        "image": {
          "sLink": "j1"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 10016,
        "title": {
          "English": "L2"
        },
        "value": "L2",
        "properties": null,
        "image": {
          "sLink": "j2"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 10015,
        "title": {
          "English": "L3"
        },
        "value": "L3",
        "properties": null,
        "image": {
          "sLink": "j3"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 10014,
        "title": {
          "English": "L4"
        },
        "value": "L4",
        "properties": null,
        "image": {
          "sLink": "j4"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 10013,
        "title": {
          "English": "L5"
        },
        "value": "L5",
        "properties": {
          "show_rules": null,
          "show_rules_logic_map": null
        },
        "image": {
          "sLink": "j5"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```